# How does NODE_BLACKLIST work in the config.py of PGAdmin with Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, pgadmin

I'm looking at using the NODE_BLACKLIST setting in PGAdmin with docker compose so as to hide nodes I don't want to see in PGAdmin.

```
# DO NOT CHANGE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING!
# List of treeview browser nodes to skip when dynamically loading
NODE_BLACKLIST = []
```

I'm not sure what the syntax should be in docker compose for it to work. I've tried a bunch of variations to no avail

```
  PGADMIN_CONFIG_NODE_BLACKLIST: catalogs, casts
```

[image: Docker Compose Output]